# System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

hasta me doy cuenta que el código  que pase en realidad es de el apartado de ventas y ese si da por que el ddl si trabaja directamente con int, en el caso de productos, hice una conexion de datos al ddl atraves de asistente

```
<div class="form-group">
                       <label>Marca</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMarca" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMarca" DataTextField="Marca" DataValueField="Marca" Width="184px" AutoPostBack="True">
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMarca" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SistemCSTConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Marca] FROM [MARCAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Categoria</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategoria" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCate" DataTextField="Categoria" DataValueField="Categoria" Width="184px" AutoPostBack="True">
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SistemCSTConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Categoria] FROM [CATEGORIAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Y en caso del estos dos la relación esta obviamente con el id de sus respectivas tablas, pero como seria difícil identificar marcas o categorías por id, quise que mostrara el nombre de la categoría y creo que es ahí donde esta el problema pero no se como solucionarlo

Tengo dos `DropDownList` y en la base de datos son dos claves foráneas en una tabla, como saben tipo `int`, pero en mi proyecto de ASP.NET hice un llenado de los dos DDL con `SqlDataSource` para que me salgan los nombres de las categorías y marca y no ingresar un 1 o 2 ya que si tengo muchas marcas o categorías seria difícil identificarlos, pero al momento de dar guardar me dice que no tiene el formato correcto. Aquí el mensaje:

> La excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
>     System.Number.StringToNumber(string,
>   System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer,
>   System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)
>     System.Number.ParseInt32(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles,
>   System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)    System.Convert.ToInt32(string)
>       CapaPresentacion.fmrProductos.btnAgregar_Click(object, System.EventArgs) en fmrProductos.aspx.cs
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(string)
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string)
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler,
>   string)
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool, bool)

[![Tabla][1]][1]

Les dejo el codigo que uso en C#:

```
protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

            cn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ProductosCreateOrUpdate", cn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (hfProductoID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfProductoID.Value)));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", txtDescripcion.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idmarca", Convert.ToInt32(ddlMarca.SelectedValue?.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcategoria", Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategoria.SelectedValue?.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@existencia", Convert.ToInt32(txtExistencia.Text.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioA", float.Parse(txtprecioA.Text.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioB", float.Parse(txtpreciob.Text.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioC", float.Parse(txtprecioc.Text.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioD", float.Parse(txtpreciod.Text.Trim()));
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        string id = hfProductoID.Value;
        clear();


        if (id == "")
            lblSuccesseMessage.Text = "Agregado Correctamente";
        else
            lblSuccesseMessage.Text = "Modificado Correctamente";

        FillGridView();


    }
```

```
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[ProductosCreateOrUpdate]
@id int,
@descripcion varchar(100),
@idmarca int,
@idcategoria int,
@existencia int,
@precioA float,
@precioB float,
@precioC float,
@precioD float
AS
If(@id=0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS(descripcion, idMarca, idCateg, existencia, precioA, precioB,
    precioC,PrecioD)
    VALUES (@descripcion, @idmarca, @idcategoria, @existencia, @precioA, @precioB,
    @precioC, @PrecioD)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUCTOS
    SET
    descripcion = @descripcion,
    idMarca= @idmarca, 
    idCateg=@idcategoria,
    existencia =@existencia,
    precioA=@precioA,
    precioB=@precioB,
    precioC=@precioC,
    PrecioD=@PrecioD
    WHERE id_prod = @id
    END


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siU3U.png
```

Comment: Hola! Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el mensaje completo de error.

Comment: Como te dice el mensaje, algo no tiene el formato correcto. Además ves que falla en la función 'StringToNumber', así que parece que alguno de tus campos a los que aplicas el `Convert.ToInt32` no es un número entero. Debuguea y comprueba esos campos (apostaría por el ddlDescripcion.Text :P)

Comment: por la definicion de SP para ver si coinciden tus datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la siguiente línea, se intenta convertir un string en un entero:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", Convert.ToInt32(ddlDescripcion.Text.Trim()));
```

ddlDescripcion.Text puede o no ser int. Puedes consultar las excepciones aquí: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Itiliza Int32. TryParse (valor, número de salida) en su lugar para resolver el problema.

Deval Ringwala responde a una pregunta similar aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269254/how-to-resolve-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-error

Comment: Añadi otra info leela porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Hola coincido con Maria Antignolo, también debes verificar que el metodo Trim(), no tengo una objeto null porque eso causa una exception, puedes probar esto:

`sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", Convert.ToInt32(ddlDescripcion.Text?.Trim()));`

Nota que coloque un signo de ? despues de Text
si el objeto es null "?" no permitira que se ejecute un metodo sobre algo null y evitar romper la aplicación.
Saludos